# Magento 2.2.6 configurable product page load slow!

Tags: product-page

I have one Magento website with a few configurable products.Each configurable product associated with minimum 12 simple products..Those simple products are showing in swatch so user need to select when open that configurable product.But when user open the product details page in front end side it is loading very slow first time (approx 31 sec).But  when open second time it is taking 3.8 sec.I am using out of the box Magento profiler and it says

> Timer Id =
>   "../view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/templates/product/view/renderer.phtml"
>   Time = 31.185969

Avg = 31.185969
Cnt =1
Emalloc = 671,624
RealMem = 0
please suggest me how to optimize loading time for first time page open.

Thanks : )

Comment: You have fixed this issue. I am also geeting same issue